# Api twitter response no statuses

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to display tweets for a specific hashtag. The code below works perfectly what ever the hashtag is, but when i try with the specific one, it doesn't work. For the last month, it worked perfectly with the right hashtag but since yesterday it's broken. (i didn't put my tokens in the code)

```
require_once('twitter-api-php-master/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "my_tokens",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "my_tokens",
    'consumer_key' => "my_tokens",
    'consumer_secret' => "my_tokens"
);

$hashtag = 'smartspend_eu';

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = "?q=#$hashtag";
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
```

The response is :

```
{"statuses":[],"search_metadata":{"completed_in":0.053,"max_id":1105019731759656961,"max_id_str":"1105019731759656961","query":"%23SMARTSPEND_EU","refresh_url":"?since_id=1105019731759656961&q=%23SMARTSPEND_EU&include_entities=1","count":15,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}}
```

What is the problem, and what can i do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found what's wrong. My code was right from the begining. The problem is that it's impossible to get the tweets from more than 7 days ago. And no tweets has been written for my hashtag for the last 7 days.